# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured. The included URLconf does not appear to have any patterns in it

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to do simple crud demo project API's for mobile using django rest framework and getting below error

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf '' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.

**Project Name :** crud_demo

**App Name** : crud_operations

**crud_demo/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()


urlpatterns= [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^crud_operations/', include('crud_operations.urls')),
]
```

**crud_operations/models.py**

```
  from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Member(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=40)
```

**crud_operations/serializers.py**

```
from crud_operations.models import Member
from rest_framework import serializers

class MemberSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Member
        fields = ('firstname', 'lastname')
```

**crud_operations/urls.py**

```
from crud_operations import views

urlpatterns = [
     url(r'^models/$', include(views.model_list)),
     url(r'^models/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$', include(views.model_detail)),
]
```

**crud_operations/views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from .models import Member
from crud_operations.serializers import MemberSerializer

@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def model_list(request):
    if request == 'GET':
        member = Member.objects.all()
        serializer = MemberSerializer(member)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    elif request == 'POST':
        serializer = MemberSerializer(data=request.DATA)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    return Response({'key': request}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)


@api_view(['GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
def model_detail(request, pk):
    try:
        member = Member.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except Member.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    if request == 'GET':
        serializer = MemberSerializer(member)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    elif request == 'PUT':
        serializer = MemberSerializer(member, data=request.DATA)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    elif request.method == 'DELETE':
        member.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)

    return Response({'key': 'value'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

**EDIT for Rohan Varma Answer**
After changed crud_demo/urls.py

```
from crud_operations import views

urlpatterns = [
     url(r'^models/$', views.model_list),
     url(r'^models/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$', views.model_detail),
]
```

Getting below error :
[image: Error 1]

**EDIT For Exprator Answer**
After changed crud_demo/urls.py
    from crud_operations import views

```
    urlpatterns = [
          path(r'^models/$', views.model_list),
          path(r'^models/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$', views.model_detail),
    ]
```

Getting below error :
[image: Error2]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you are using django 2.0.1 you should be aware that django has changed its urlpatterns from django 2.0
use the below code in your urls and remove that admin.autodiscover() as its not needed

```
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('articles/2003/', views.special_case_2003),
    path('articles/<yyyy:year>/', views.year_archive),
    ...
]
```

change this line

```
path(r'^models/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$', views.model_detail),
```

to

```
path('models/<int:pk>/', views.model_detail),
```

and

```
path(r'^models/$', views.model_list),
```

to

```
path('models/', views.model_list),
```

**As for Django 4.2.1**:
if you use the **@login_required** decorator on a view and you provide the 'login_url' argument ensure that its value is either a
plain url or view name.
i.e.
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

avoid this: as it will throw an the above mentioned error

```
@login_required(login_url=reverse("login"))
def home(request):
    return render(request, "auth_test/home.html")
```

rather use;

```
@login_required(login_url="login")
def home(request):
    return render(request, "auth_test/home.html")
```

Django will automatically determine if what was provided is a url
or a view name and it will handle the necessary resolving

[Here is a screen shot of the error in the vscode terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkisF.png)

The above mentioned error is reproducible if that is done

Comment: Okay But now I am getting My Edit 1 issue after changing above lines. request == 'GET' is not true in views.py. Please can you help on this. Please refer EDIT for Rohan Varma Answer

Comment: thats a different question, you need to put it as a question with the view code of that particular url, hope you understand the rule of stackoverflow

Comment: Really can't understand WHY they can't just leave the code alone (as in backwards compatible). All these useless, unrequested "features" only end up costing time.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in crud_operations/urls.py because you are using `include` to try and link the view to the url. `include` is for linking a url to another url.py set of configurations. To link a view function to the url, simply type the name of the function there as such:

```
from crud_operations import views

urlpatterns = [
     url(r'^models/$', views.model_list),
     url(r'^models/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$', views.model_detail),
]
```

Good luck!